# Conditional expectation knowing $X$ and knowing $f(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am wondering in which cases the following equality is true: for $X$, $Y$ two random variables and $f$, $g$ two functions,

$$\mathrm{Var}\left[\mathbb{E} ( f(g(X),Y) | X ) \right] = 
      \mathrm{Var}\left[\mathbb{E} ( f(g(X),Y) | g(X) ) \right]. $$

My guess is that the function $g$ should be **injective** but I did not manage to prove it or to find the proof in literature...

Any help or piece of advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g$ is injective, $E(Z\mid X)=E(Z\mid g(X))$ for every integrable random variable $Z$ hence the result holds.

Otherwise, the result usually fails. Assume for example that $X$ is integrable, $Y=X$, $g:x\mapsto x^2$, $f:(x,y)\mapsto y$, and that the distribution of $X$ is symmetric. 
Then $f(g(X),Y)=X$ hence $$E(f(g(X),Y)\mid X)=E(X\mid X)=X,\qquad E(f(g(X),Y)\mid g(X))=E(X\mid X^2)=0,$$ which shows that the variances do not coincide in general.

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide a proof or a link to a proof for the first result?

Comment: Proof: For every measurable function $h$ and random variable $U$, $\sigma(h(U))\subseteq\sigma(U)$. Apply this twice.

Comment: But to do that, $g$ needs to be bijective, isn't it?

Comment: My last comment states a result valid for every function $h$, bijective or not.

Comment: It is not what I meant. You said that it is necessary to apply your last result twice: you mean that it must be applied on $f$ and $f^{-1}$, isn't it? Like in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372542/how-can-a-sigma-algebra-be-treated-or-computed-example ? If it is true, $f$ need to be bijective.

Comment: Actually, $g$ injective is enough, since then there exists $k$ such that $k\circ g$ is identity, hence $\sigma(X)=\sigma(k(g(X)))\subseteq\sigma(g(X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$.